# How should I get the minimum of a sum of root square and a linear part

Tags: algebra-precalculus

$\frac {\sqrt{x^2 + 100}}  a + \frac {b - x}  c$

where $a$, $b$, $c$ are positive constants.

I can draw the curve in a graph paper and get the minimum, but don't know how to calculate it in a mathematical way?

Comment: Take the derivative, set it to zero.

Comment: It may not have a minimum, for example if $a$ is negative and $c$ is positive, you can make it as small as you want by taking $x$ large enough.  You can certainly do it with calculus, but I don't see how to do it without calculus.  BTW, I removed the quadratic forms tag.  This isn't a quadratic form.  If you aren't certain what a tag means, it's better to leave it off.

Comment: @saulspatz sorry they are positive, just updated the question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The most straightforward way to do this is by taking the derivative and setting it to 0, as Ross Millikan commented.

Let

$$ y = \frac{\sqrt{x^2+100}}{a} + \frac{b-x}{c} $$

Then, differentiating, we have

$$ \frac{dy}{dx} = \frac{2x}{2a\sqrt{x^2+100}} - \frac{1}{c} $$

Setting $ y' = 0 $, we have

$$ \frac{2x}{2a\sqrt{x^2+100}} - \frac{1}{c} = 0 $$

After a bit of algebra, we get to

$$ x = \frac{10a}{\sqrt{c^2-a^2}} $$

You can use the second derivative test to confirm that it is a minimum, and not a maximum.

Given that the parameters $ a, b, c > 0$, we have:

- $ c > a $ : The minimum is at the unique local minimum we solved for, $ x = \frac{10a}{\sqrt{c^2 - a^2}} $
- $ c \le a$ : $ y' < 0 $ everywhere, so there are no local minima, but on any bounded interval, the minimum will be at the greatest value of $x$ on the interval.